# Access window object from a background Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to access the properties of a `window` object from a background script. I have this in `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "..": "..",
    "permissions": ["http://*.mysite.net/"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["extension.js"]
    }
}
```

and this in `extension.js`:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {

        var tabWindowObject = ??

        setInterval(tabWindowObject.someFunction, 10);
    }
});
```

I need it here, not in another place (no content scripts and no script injection). How do I get the `tabWindowObject` in `extension.js`? In other words, I want to access the context of a tab inside a background script Chrome extension.

Comment: You can't. If it's an object defined by the webpage code, then you can only access it through script injection from a content script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. The extension's background page runs in one [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), while the tab that was updated runs in a separate process. Different processes can't share objects, so you can't directly access the `window` object of a tab from an extension's background page. You have to use a [content script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) to get extension code to run inside the tab's process.

Comment: And then I have to inject code using `<script>` tags to pass messages from the web page to the content script and from the content script to the background script. I figured it out after a lot of searching, so I'm just adding to your answer. There's no way to access objects, but I can send JSON data (which is serialized into strings when passed to message listeners).

Comment: You may be able to avoid the `<script>` tags, depending on exactly what you need to do: the web page can fire events on DOM objects, and the content script can listen to those.